# Process invoked from python thread keeps on running on closing main process

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a `Tkinter` wrapper written over `robocopy.exe`, the code is organized as shown below :-

**Tkinter Wrapper :**

- Spawns a new thread and pass the arguments, which includes source/destination and other parameters

(Note : `Queue` object is also passed to thread, since the thread will read the output from `robocopy` and will put in `queue`, main tkinter thread will keep on polling `queue` and will update Tkinter text widget with the output)

Code Snippet

```
... Code to poll queue and update tk widget ...

q = Queue.Queue()
t1 = threading.Thread(target=CopyFiles,args=(q,src,dst,), kwargs={"ignore":ignore_list})
t1.daemon = True
t1.start()
```

**Thread :** (In a separate file)

Below is the code snippet from thread

```
def CopyFiles(q,src,dst,ignore=None):
    extra_args =  ['/MT:15', '/E', '/LOG:./log.txt', '/tee', '/r:2', '/w:2']
    if len(ignore) > 0:
        extra_args.append('/xf')
        extra_args.extend(ignore)
        extra_args.append('/xd')
        extra_args.extend(ignore)
    command_to_pass = ["robocopy",src, dst]
    command_to_pass.extend(extra_args)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command_to_pass,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
      line = proc.stdout.readline()
      if line == '':
        break
      q.put(line.strip())
```

Code which is called, when tkinter application is closed :-

```
def onQuit(self):
    global t1
    if t1.isAlive():
        pass
    if tkMessageBox.askyesno("Title", "Do you really want to exit?"):
        self.destroy()
        self.master.destroy()
```

**Problem**

Whenever, I close the tkinter application when `robocopy` is running, python application closes but the `robocopy.exe` keeps on running.

I have tried setting the thread as daemon, but it has no effect. How can I stop `robocopy.exe` when `onQuit` method is called?

Answer (score 0):

To simplify things let's ignore Tkinter and the fact that a separate thread is used.

The situation is that your app spawns a subprocess to execute an external program (*robocopy.exe* in this question), and you'd need to stop the spawned program from you're application on a certain event (when the Tkinter app is closing in this question).

This requires an inter process communication mechanism, so the spawned process would be notified of the event, and reacts accordingly. A common mechanism is to use signals provided by the OS.

You could send a signal (SIGTERM) to the external process and ask from it to quit. Assuming that the program reacts to signal as expected (most well written applications do) you'll get the desired behavior (the process will terminate).

Using the [terminate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate) method on the subprocess will send the proper signal of current platform to the subprocess.

You'd need a reference to the subprocess object `proc` in the `onQuit` function (from the provided code I see `onQuit` is a function and not an object method, so it could use a global variable to access `proc`), so you can call the `terminate` method of the process:

```
def onQuit(self):
    global t1, proc
    if t1.isAlive():
        pass
    # by the way I'm not sure about the logic, but I guess this
    # below statement should be an elif instead of if
    if tkMessageBox.askyesno("Title", "Do you really want to exit?"):
        proc.terminate()
        self.destroy()
        self.master.destroy()
```

This code assumes you're storing the reference to the subprocess in the global scope, so you'd have to modify the `CopyFiles` as well.

I'm not sure how *robocopy* handles terminate signals and I'm guessing that's not something that we have any control over.

If you had more control on the external program (could modify the source), there might have been more options, for example sending messages using stdio, or using a shared memory, etc.

Comment: Actually, I never had used Signals before. It would be helpful, if you can provide some example (pointers in this context). Do I need to set `signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sighandler)` in the Tkinter wrapper ? But my suprocess has been spawned from different thread, so how can i communicate with `proc` object

Comment: I just updated the answer with some example. You may use `signal.signal` if you need to define how you're app (The Tkitner wrapper) would react when a signal is received by the process. But in this question, you're app is sending the signal, and *robocopy* is the one who needs to handle the signal. So `signal.signal` is not helpful.

Comment: thanks, actually onQuit is a method (I have skipped a lot of code), actually question remains - how can I pass the `proc` object from thread to main application, because `proc` is created inside thread and `onQuit` method is in Tkinter wrapper

Comment: As stated in the answer you can use a global variable to store a reference to `proc`. So define the variable in the global scope (like where you defined the Queue `q`), and then store the reference to the subprocess in `CopyFile` in that variable. There are other options to share data between functions, for example if both functions were methods of the same object, then `proc` could have been an instance attribute of that object. But this requires a different design from the one provided in this question. IMHO this design would be a better choice than using global variables.